# Parent child relationship between currency

Tags: database, hierarchy, currency

I need to create a database table structure for representing all the currencies, I will have to create a self referencing table if there is more than 2 levels of hierarchy in any of country's currency. But if all currencies only have two levels (e.g. Dollar>Cent, Rupees>Paisa etc.), then I can represent it only in two columns of same table, with ParentCurrency and ChildCurrency.

Does anyone knows if all currencies in the world always have only two levels?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can accept your answer if you answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a question about programming ... but yes according to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies

Answer (score 0):

Let's say all the currencies in the world have two levels. One day a country introduces a third level and all your design which is assuming that all the currencies have two levels will fail to be correct.

In my opinion you should have a Countries table:

Countries(ID, name)

And you should have a Currencies table:

Currencies(ID, CountryID, ParentID, unity, sign)

where ParentID of cent would be dollar, sign would be $ for dollar. You need to separate the country from the currency because there are countries with more than one currency, particulary countries which introduced euro and use their old currency as well.

Comment: "One day a country introduces a third level and all your design which is assuming that all the currencies have two levels will fail to be correct" This is very unlikely and you are artificially complicating the model. http://techgraffiti.blogspot.com/2009/03/kiss-dry-and-yagni.html take a look at this post.

Comment: @Agustin Cautin: For instance Romania introduced RON a few years ago and for a few years both ROL and RON was used, 100 Bani = 1 ROL, 10000 ROL = 1 RON. To further complicate matters, another type of Bani was used, being 100 Bani(of the other type) = 1 RON. As a matter of fact we can say that what I've mentioned is possible indeed, we also have a precedent.

Comment: The point is that happened "a few years ago" and it will maybe happen again "some years from now". Currencies as countries, move slow, a lot slower that software and by trying to fulfill this artificial request the system is getting more complex.

Comment: I disagree. If you create your database now knowing that your design works for the current situation and it might not work in the future is like sitting on a dynamite, without knowing whether it will explode. When planning a database scheme one should think about all the possible situations and the design and code should be bullet-proof.